# how to convert date to mysql format in python

Tags: python, mysql, date

How to convert date to mysql date format like  Dec 21, 2019 to 2019-12-21 in python.

Please help, I am new to python.

i tried date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") but its won't work.

Comment: Please specify exactly *how* it doesn't work, what error you get, etc. Also please post a [short example of working code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can try to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the correct format string.

```
import datetime
d = datetime.datetime.strptime("Dec 21, 2019","%b %d, %Y")
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

If you're not sure about the format of date and/or expecting multiple formats, you can use the below code snippet

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d = parse("Dec 21, 2019")
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score -1):

Example snippet for date conversion.

```
 from datetime import datetime
 oldformat = 'Dec 21, 2019'
 datetimeobject = datetime.strptime(oldformat,'%b %d, %Y')
 newformat = datetimeobject.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
 print(newformat)
```